# Converting Text Document from English to Chinese in Tx Text control Winform third party developed tool

Tags: c#, winforms, vsto, txtextcontrol

Culture setting for Tx Text Control Tool is

```
EditorControl.Selection.Culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

While importing normal word file to Tx Text control converted to chinese.
User installed Microsoft pinyin IME for keyboard input.

Please help to provide solution not to convert it to chinese?

Comment: Have you tried asking TextControl developers?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question belong to TextControl developers/support.

Comment: Did you have a chance to contact the TextControl developers?

Comment: I believe you´re facing a problem related to import WORD file directly into TextControl (there are some problems corrected in SP1 related to this). Try:  1) update your TxControl via Service Pack;   2) Try to import as RTF instead WORD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this Formatting Issue